# Mongoid returns model with id despite the fact that id is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

There are records in my database with null `_id`, but mongoid model returns record with filled, nonexistent `_id`:

```
MyModel.where('deleted_at' => { '$exists' => false }).first
#=> #<MyModel _id: 581208bcfca2f42fb9c9faa0...
```

But when I search this model in mongo client:

```
>db.my_model.find({deleted_at: null})[0]
{
  "_id": null,
  ....
}
```

When I try to find this record in rails console:

```
MyModel.where(id: "581208bcfca2f42fb9c9faa0").count
=> 0
```

Is there any explanation for this case?

Answer (score 1):

The `_id` field is the primary key for every document. It's called `_id` and is also accessible via `id`. From [Mongo Code Source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/fields.rb#L47) you can see the alias internally.

Also you can find this information, here in [Documents Fields docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/).

Mongo advises using the `_id` field: [BSON and ObjectID docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)